# How do I add Webkit webview to the Ubuntu SDK?

Tags: application-development, html5, webkit, sdk

I'm trying to do this tutorial for learning and it seems that I have to keep adding things for it to go smoothly. http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/html-5/tutorial/

I don't have the "rss-sample.qml" file at all in my project. I don't even have the html folder. Also as the tutorial shows, it's supposed to have the option for HTML5 Touch UI project but I had to use HTML5 Tabbed Touch UI instead because that's the closest option I have. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML5 tutorial is outdated due to code changes in the SDK PPA. Very sorry for the confusion. For example, as you note, at the time the tutorial was written, there were two types of HTML5 app projects you could create: one for Cordova HTML5 apps, one for non Cordova HTML5 apps (which was named "HTML5 Touch UI"). There is now only a single type of HTML5 app project that supports all functionality. Another change is that HTML5 apps no longer have or need a qml file, as you noted.

The HTML5 app support is under rapid development now, so stay tuned for news of important enhancements of functionality!

Comment: What do you recommend then for those who are planning to code for Ubuntu ? I am planning to code but not sure if to choose QML or HTML5.

Comment: Both QML and HTML5 are good choices for Ubuntu app dev. HTML5 is a good choice for those with some existing web tech experience with the caveat that the first Ubuntu HTML5 framework release is not yet final. QML has the lead in implementation as an Ubuntu app toolkit with a stable API released, so that's a great choice too.